# javascript href hover deselection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I have this code in HTML:

```
   $('#icon_index a[href="#profilo_page"]').hover(
    function () {
       $(this).children("img").attr("src", "img/profilo_p.png");
    },
    function () {
       $(this).children("img").attr("src", "img/profilo_n.png");
    }
  );
```

when I use this command:

```
$.mobile.changePage("#index_page");
```

the image will remain selected. While, if I use the changePage command for another page and then for the index_page it works.
Is there a solution to make "deselected" the image after click without navigation in other pages?

Comment: The question is not very clear, what does the first code have to do with the second?

Comment: Seeing the words "hover" and "mobile" in the same piece of code makes me nervous. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hover do not exist on a smartphone.  In most ocations hover will be intercepted as a "click".

So lets say you have some sort of menubar like this.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sublink</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So when you hover the link called "home" the sub menu will popup with the link "sublink" in it.

On a webpage you are right that it will be enabled on mouse hover, but on a smartphone you can click it instead.

Regarding the removal.  I dont think that your approach is the right things to do.  Hover is not for smartphones, so i would totally not use hover.

I dont think you can directy remove what you are asking for.  Then again, what you are doing is already apart from what is doable on a smartphone.